# How to extrapolate a raster using in R

Tags: r, r-raster, pde

I am trying to downscale climatic conditions using the methodology in [this](https://www.clim-past-discuss.net/11/2585/2015/cpd-11-2585-2015.pdf) article using the R software. I am almost there, but I am missing a couple of steps

### Packages and data needed

For this example I uploaded some data to the archive.org website to load the required packages and data used in this example use the following code:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

download.file("https://archive.org/download/Downscaling/BatPatagonia.rds", "Bat.rds")
download.file("https://archive.org/download/Downscaling/TempMinPatNow.rds", "Tmin.rds")

BatPatagonia <- readRDS("Bat.rds")
TempMinPatNow <- readRDS("Tmin.rds")
```

BatPatagonia is a raster file with the Bathymetry and altitude of the area extracted and transformed from the GEBCO dataset, while the TempMinPatNow is the minimum temperature of the same area for January extracted from WorldClim. The plots of the datasets are seen below:

[image]

### The goal of this question

In order to downscale past data from the last glacial maximum I need to model how current climate would be like if the sea level was the same as it was in the past. In order to do that I use the GEBCO data and to figure out more or less were the coast was. According to the methodology in the article cited above this are the first three steps to follow:

1. Create a DEM for land above 20 meters above sea level
2. Calculate a Multiple Linear Regression in a moving window
3. **Extrapolate coefficients to the ocean**

Point 3 is what I have been struggling to do, I will show how I did the first 2 points, and show what I have been looking for trying to solve point 3

#### 1. Create a DEM for land 20 meters above sea level

In order to do this I took the *BatPatagonia* raster, and replaced all values below 20 meters with NA values using the following code:

```
Elev20 <- BatPatagonia

values(Elev20) <- ifelse(values(Elev20) <= 20, NA, values(Elev20))
```

The resulting raster is shown in the following image

[image]

#### 2. Calculate a Multiple Linear Regression in a moving window

According to the manuscript in page 2591, the next step is to do a Multiple Linear Regression in a moving window using the Following formula for altitudes over 20 meters:

[image]

We already have the elevation data, but we also need the rasters for latitude and longitude, for that we use the following code, where we first create the Latitude and Longitude Rasters:

```
Latitud <- BatPatagonia
Longitud <- BatPatagonia

data_matrix <- raster::xyFromCell(BatPatagonia, 1:ncell(BatPatagonia))

values(Latitud) <- data_matrix[, 2]
values(Longitud) <- data_matrix[, 1]
```

We will multiply this by a raster mask of the areas that have elevations over 20 meters, so that we get only the values that we need:

```
Elev20Mask <- BatPatagonia

values(Elev20Mask) <- ifelse(values(Elev20Mask) <= 20, NA, 1)

Longitud <- Elev20Mask*Longitud

Latitud <- Elev20Mask*Latitud
```

Now I will build a stack with the response variables and the predictor variables:

```
Preds <- stack(Elev20, Longitud, Latitud, TempMinPatNow)

names(Preds) <- c("Elev", "Longitud", "Latitud", "Tmin")
```

The resulting stack is shown in the following figure:

[image]

As stated in the paper the moving window should be of 25 by 25 cells, resulting in a total of 625 cells, however they state that if the moving window has less than 170 cells with data, the regression should not be performed, and it should have a maximum of 624 cells in order to ensure that we are only modelling areas close to the coast.

The result of this Multiple Regression with the moving window should be a stack with the Local intercept, and the local estimation of each one of the Betas that are in the equation shown above. I found out how to make this using the following code using the `getValuesFocal` function (This loop takes a while):

```
# First we establish the 25 by 25 window

w <- c(25, 25)

# Then we create the empty layers for the resulting stack

intercept <- Preds[[1]]
intercept[] <- NA

elevationEst <- intercept

latitudeEst <- intercept

longitudeEst <- intercept
```

Now we start the code:

```
for (rl in 1:nrow(Preds)) {
  v <- getValuesFocal(Preds[[1:4]], row = rl, nrows = 1, ngb = w, array = FALSE)
  int <- rep(NA, nrow(v[[1]]))
  x1 <- rep(NA, nrow(v[[1]]))
  x2 <- rep(NA, nrow(v[[1]]))
  x3 <- rep(NA, nrow(v[[1]]))
  x4 <- rep(NA, nrow(v[[1]]))
  for (i in 1:nrow(v[[1]])) {
    xy <- na.omit(data.frame(x1 = v[[1]][i, ], x2 = v[[2]][i, ], x3 = v[[3]][i, 
                                                                         ], y = v[[4]][i, ]))
    
    if (nrow(xy) > 170 & nrow(xy) <= 624) {
      coefs <- coefficients(lm(as.numeric(xy$y) ~ as.numeric(xy$x1) + 
                             as.numeric(xy$x2) + as.numeric(xy$x3)))
      int[i] <- coefs[1]
      x1[i] <- coefs[2]
      x2[i] <- coefs[3]
      x3[i] <- coefs[4]
    } else {
      int[i] <- NA
      x1[i] <- NA
      x2[i] <- NA
      x3[i] <- NA
    }
  }

  intercept[rl, ] <- int
  elevationEst[rl, ] <- x1
  longitudeEst[rl, ] <- x2
  latitudeEst[rl, ] <- x3

  message(paste(rl, "of", nrow(Preds), "ready"))
}

Coeffs <- stack(intercept, elevationEst, latitudeEst, longitudeEst, (intercept + Preds$Elev * elevationEst + Preds$Longitud * longitudeEst + Preds$Latitud *latitudeEst), Preds$Tmin)

names(Coeffs) <- c("intercept", "elevationEst", "longitudeEst", "latitudeEst", "fitted", "Observed")
```

The result of this loop is the `coeffs` stack, shown below:

[image]

## This is where I got stuck

#### Extrapolate coefficients to the ocean

The goal now is to extrapolate the first 4 rasters of the Coeffs stack (intercept, elevationEst, longitudeEst and latitudeEst) to where the coast should be according to the last glacial maximum which was 120 meters shallower

```
MaxGlacier <- BatPatagonia

values(MaxGlacier) <- ifelse(values(MaxGlacier) < -120, NA,1)
```

The projected coastline is shown in the following map:

[image]

The way the authors projected the coefficients to the coast was by filling the gaps using by solving Poisson's equation using the `poisson_grid_fill` of the NCL language from [NCAR](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Functions/Built-in/poisson_grid_fill.shtml). But I would like to keep it simple and try to do all in the same language. I also found a similar function in [Python](https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2014/10/20/gridfill/).

I would be happy with any extrapolation process that works well, I am not limiting my search to that algorithm.

I found several R packages that fill gaps such as the [Gapfill](https://git.math.uzh.ch/florian.gerber/gapfill) package and even found a [review of methods](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8276645) to fill gaps, but most of them are for interpolating and mostly for NDVI layers that can be based on other layers where the gap is filled.

How can I move forward on this?

Comment: Did you try kriging to predict the missing values in the 4 rasters of the Coeffs stack?

Comment: @Florian, could you elaborate on how to use that method in this particular problem? I would think you would need the predictors in the missing values, or am I wrong?

Comment: Note that you can already simplify your code and immediately obtain `Elev20 = mask(BatPatagonia, BatPatagonia <= 20, maskvalue = 1)`, `Longitud = mask(init(BatPatagonia, 'x'), Elev20)` and `Latitud = mask(init(BatPatagonia, 'y'), Elev20)` ;-)

Comment: Thank you @ztl, I will edit the code later to improve it with your more efficient code

Comment: Why you get this black holes in the Coeffs stack?

Comment: Given a spatial field (say a raster with one layer) one can predict the value at any spatial location with Kriging. See the R packages `gstat` or `fields`.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question.

Comment: @Florian It has those "holes" because according to the manuscript linked you have to model the "coastal conditions" first, check it on the methodology of the link I sent

Comment: @Florian I debated weather to put it there, but since I have more reputation in this forum I can give a bounty, I cant in the gis.stackexchange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thinking back several decades to my physics undergrad days, we used Laplace relaxation to solve these types of Poisson equation problems.  I'm not sure, but I guess that may also be how `poisson_grid_fill` works.  The process is simple.  Relaxation is an iterative process where we calculate each cell **except those that form the boundary condition** as the mean of the cells that are horizontally or vertically adjacent, then repeat until the result approaches a stable solution.

In your case, the cells for which you already have values provide your boundary condition, and we can iterate over the others.  Something like this (demonstrated here for the intercept coefficient - you can do the others the same way):

```
gaps = which(is.na(intercept)[])
intercept.ext = intercept
w=matrix(c(0,0.25,0,0.25,0,0.25,0,0.25,0), nc=3, nr=3)
max.it = 1000
for (i in 1:max.it) intercept.ext[gaps] = focal(intercept.ext, w=w, na.rm=TRUE)[gaps]
intercept.ext = mask(intercept.ext, MaxGlacier)
```

**Edit**

Here's the same process embedded in a function, to demonstrate how you might use a `while` loop that continues until a desired tolerance is reached (or maximum number of iterations is exceeded).  Note that this function is to demonstrate the principle, and is not optimised for speed.

```
gap.fill = function(r, max.it = 1e4, tol = 1e-2, verbose=FALSE) {
  gaps = which(is.na(r)[])
  r.filled = r
  w = matrix(c(0,0.25,0,0.25,0,0.25,0,0.25,0), nc=3, nr=3)
  i = 0
  while(i < max.it) {
    i = i + 1
    new.vals = focal(r.filled, w=w, na.rm=TRUE)[gaps]
    max.residual = suppressWarnings(max(abs(r.filled[gaps] - new.vals), na.rm = TRUE))
    if (verbose) print(paste('Iteration', i, ': residual = ', max.residual))
    r.filled[gaps] = new.vals
    if (is.finite(max.residual) & max.residual <= tol) break
  }
  return(r.filled)
}

intercept.ext = gap.fill(intercept)
intercept.ext = mask(intercept.ext, MaxGlacier)
plot(stack(intercept, intercept.ext))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. FWIW, the help page for [`poisson_grid_fill`](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Document/Functions/Built-in/poisson_grid_fill.shtml) shows that the function takes a "relaxation coefficient" as one argument, which is consistent with your guess about the method it uses.

Comment: Nice @dww, I will check the answer a little more closely

Comment: @dww it all seems great. One question though, it seems to me that you are not using max.it in the code. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Hi - it was just a simple version I showed.  All I use max.it for is to determine the number of times to run the loop.  A more thorough function would probably use a threshold value to keep running the loop indefinitely until the cell values change less than the threshold.  And use max.it to break out of the loop if it goes on too long.

Comment: Thanks again @dww, so using a while loop, could you add a working example on the code for that part? Thanks

Comment: Thank you @dww, I will wait an hour or so, but I really doubt anyone can have a better answer, then I will give you the Bounty