# fill NA raster cells using focal defined by boundary

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, terra

I have a raster and a shapefile. The raster contains NA and I am filling the NAs using the `focal` function

```
library(terra)

v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
r[45:60, 45:60] <- NA
  
r_fill <- terra::focal(r, 5, mean, na.policy="only", na.rm=TRUE)
```

However, there are some NA still left. So I do this:

```
na_count <- terra::freq(r_fill, value = NA)

while(na_count$count != 0){
  
 r_fill <- terra::focal(r_fill, 5, mean, na.policy="only", na.rm=TRUE)  
 na_count <- terra::freq(r_fill, value = NA)
}
```

Once all NA's are filled, I clip the raster again using the shapefile

```
r_fill  <- terra::crop(r_fill, v, mask = T, touches = T)
```

This is what my before and after looks like:

[image]

I wondered if the while loop is an efficient way to fill the NAs or basically determine how many times I have to run `focal` to fill all the NAs in the raster.

Comment: Finding out how many times you need to run focal might be hard. At the moment, your while loop continues to impute N/As until the whole raster is filled. However, it would be more efficient if you could impute N/As until there are none left within the shapefill. That requires determining the contour of your shapefill and counting N/As only within.

Comment: Rather than being inefficient, your loop could actually terminate too soon! You are essentially using a gap filling method known as relaxation, which should really be continued until the missing region changes by less than a threshold amount on each iteration.  Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53798137/2761575) which shows how to do this using focal in raster. Updating that solution to use terra should be fairly trivial.

Comment: [terra focal 930](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/930), [terra focal 907](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/907), my terra - 1.7.6, given @dww 'how focal results are implemented vs my likely naive, focal was done, and as per discussion above is actively under development/refinement, putting your version above would be useful for future searchers..

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we can, or want to, dispense with the `while(` altogether by making a better estimate of `focal(`'s `w=` arg in a world where `r`, as ground truth, isn't available. Were it available, we could readily derive direct value of `w`

```
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
# and it's variants
r2 <- r
r2[45:60, 45:60] <- NA
freq(r2, value=NA) - freq(r, value=NA)
  layer value count
1     0    NA   256
sqrt((freq(r2, value=NA) - freq(r, value=NA))$count)
[1] 16
```

which might be a good value for `w=`, and introducing another variant

```
r3 <- r
r3[40:47, 40:47] <- NA
r3[60:67, 60:67] <- NA
r3[30:37, 30:37] <- NA
r3[70:77, 40:47] <- NA
rm(r)
```

[image]

We no longer have our ground truth. How might we estimate an edge of `w=`? Turning to `boundaries(` default values (inner)

```
r2_bi <- boundaries(r2)
r3_bi <- boundaries(r3)
# examining some properties of r2_bi, r3_bi
freq(r2_bi, value=1)$count
[1] 503
freq(r3_bi, value=1)$count
[1] 579
freq(r2_bi, value=1)$count/freq(r2_bi, value = 0)$count
[1] 0.1306833
freq(r3_bi, value=1)$count/freq(r3_bi, value = 0)$count
[1] 0.1534588
sum(freq(r2_bi, value=1)$count,freq(r2_bi, value = 0)$count)
[1] 4352
sum(freq(r3_bi, value=1)$count,freq(r3_bi, value = 0)$count)
[1] 4352
```

Taken in reverse order, sum[s] and freq[s] suggest that while the total area of (let's call them holes) are the same, they differ in number and r2 is generally larger than r3. This is also clear from the first pair of freq[s].
Now we drift into some voodoo, hocus pocus in pursuit of a better edge estimate

```
    sum(freq(r2)$count) - sum(freq(r2, value = NA)$count)
    [1] 154
    sum(freq(r3)$count) - sum(freq(r3, value = NA)$count)
    [1] 154
    (sum(freq(r3)$count) - sum(freq(r3, value = NA)$count))
    [1] 12.40967
    freq(r2_bi, value=1)$count/freq(r2_bi, value = 0)$count
    [1] 0.1306833
    freq(r2_bi, value=0)$count/freq(r2_bi, value = 1)$count
    [1] 7.652087
    freq(r3_bi, value=1)$count/freq(r3_bi, value = 0)$count
    [1] 0.1534588
    taking the larger, i.e. freq(r2_bi 7.052087
    7.652087/0.1306833
    [1] 58.55444
    154+58
    [1] 212
    sqrt(212)
    [1] 14.56022
    round(sqrt(212)+1)
    [1] 16
```

Well, except for that `+1` part, maybe still a decent estimate for `w=`, to be used on both `r2` and `r3` if called upon to find a better `w`, and perhaps obviate the need for `while(`.
Another approach to looking for squares and their edges:

```
wtf3 <- values(r3_bi$elevation)
wtf2 <- values(r2_bi$elevation)
wtf2_tbl_df2 <-   as.data.frame(table(rle(as.vector(is.na(wtf2)))$lengths))
wtf3_tbl_df2 <- as.data.frame(table(rle(as.vector(is.na(wtf3)))$lengths))
names(wtf2_tbl_df2)
[1] "Var1" "Freq"
wtf2_tbl_df2[which(wtf2_tbl_df2$Var1 == wtf2_tbl_df2$Freq), ]
   Var1 Freq
14   16   16
wtf3_tbl_df2[which(wtf3_tbl_df2$Freq == max(wtf3_tbl_df2$Freq)), ]
  Var1 Freq
7    8   35
35/8
[1] 4.375 # 4 squares of 8 with 3 8 length vectors
```

bringing in `v` finally and filling

```
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r2_fill_17 <- focal(r2, 16 + 1 , mean, na.policy='only', na.rm = TRUE)
r3_fill_9 <- focal(r3, 8 + 1 , mean, na.policy='only', na.rm = TRUE)
r2_fill_17_cropv <- crop(r2_fill_17, v, mask = TRUE, touches = TRUE)
r3_fill_9_cropv <- crop(r3_fill_9, v, mask = TRUE, touches = TRUE)
```

[image]

And I now appreciate your `while(` approach as your `r2` looks better, more naturally transitioned, though the `r3` looks fine. In my few, brief experiments with smaller than 'hole', i.e. `focal(r2, 9`, I got the sense it would take 2 passes to fill, that suggests `focal(r2, 5` would take 4.

I guess further determining the proportion of `fill:hole:rast` for when to deploy a `while` would be worthwhile.