# How can I interpolate spatial values with R?

Tags: r, interpolation, raster, spatial

I´d like to interpolate missing values within raster:

```
r <- rast(xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=10, nrows=50, ncols=50)
e =  rast(xmin=2, xmax=4, ymin=2, ymax=4, nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
values(e) <- 1:ncell(e)

r=raster(r)
e=raster(e)
r[intersect(r,e)]=NA
plot(r)
```

How can I do this?

[image: missing values within raster]

I know how to interpolate between points with different methods (spline, kriging, IDW...), but I have no idea, how to do this an a polygon scale.

Comment: there's a pretty versatile method in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53798137/2761575

Answer (score 5):

As this is 2d data, you can just apply the same interpolation functions you normally use to every column of the matrix. For example, using `approx()`:

```r
r_interp <- r |>
    as.matrix() |>
    apply(MARGIN = 2, \(x) approx(x)[["y"]]) |>
    raster()

plot(r_interp)
```

[image]

You might think this only works well because every value on the x-axis is identical but it will work in other cases as well. For example if we generate a different matrix and add some more `NA` values in the visibly non-linear area:

```r
Z  <- as.matrix(r)
r_nonlin <- sapply(
    seq_len(ncol(Z)),
    \(i) Z[, i] * i
) |>
    raster()
# Create more NAs
r_nonlin[30:40, 30:40] <- NA

plot(r_nonlin)
```

[image]

We can still use the same approach:

```r
r_nonlin |>
    as.matrix() |>
    apply(MARGIN = 2, \(x) approx(x)[["y"]]) |>
    raster() |>
    plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **interpolation** package to interpolate non-gridded bivariate data.

```r
library(terra)
library(raster)

f <- function(x, y) x^2 + y^2

r <- rast(xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=10, nrows=50, ncols=50)
e <- rast(xmin=6, xmax=8, ymin=6, ymax=8, nrows=10, ncols=10)
xy <- xyFromCell(r, 1:ncell(r))
values(r) <- f(xy[, "x"], xy[, "y"])
values(e) <- 1:ncell(e)
r <- raster(r)
e <- raster(e)
r[intersect(r,e)] <- NA
plot(r)
```

[image]

```r
# interpolate
library(interpolation)
xyz <- cbind(coordinates(r), z = getValues(r))
missing <- is.na(xyz[, "z"])
fun <- interpfun(
  xyz[!missing, "x"], xyz[!missing, "y"], xyz[!missing, "z"], "linear"
)
zinterp <- fun(xyz[missing, "x"], xyz[missing, "y"])

z <- xyz[, "z"]
z[missing] <- zinterp
rinterp <- setValues(r, z)

plot(rinterp)
```

[image]