# How to interpolate missing values given a SpatRaster object in R Terra package?

Tags: r, interpolation, raster, terra, spatial-interpolation

I would like to interpolate the missing values (set to 0) within my SpatRaster object.

I created a SpatRaster object and assigned values to specific cells depending on cell coordinates:

```
raster_layer <- rast(ncol=22, nrow=11, xmin=-3819.721, xmax=1132.362, 
  ymin=-698.7546, ymax=2013.745)

for (i in 1:nrow(Test)) { #Test is the sample dataset I am pulling the coordinates 
and the cell values from.
  col_num <- Test$grid_column[i]
  row_num <- Test$grid_row[i]
  cell_value <- Test$pm1_mgm3[i] 
  
  raster_layer[row_num, col_num] <- cell_value
}
```

Plotting the raster layer gets me this result and I want to interpolate all missing values:

[Raster layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdrLY.png)

I initially used a solution from another similar question from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77751650/how-can-i-interpolate-spatial-values-with-r/77970309#77970309):

```
r_interp <- raster_layer %>%
    as.matrix() %>%
    apply(MARGIN = 2, \(x) approx(x)[["y"]]) %>%
    raster()

plot(r_interp)
```

However, I keep getting errors like "[rast,list] none of the elements of x are a SpatRaster" or "Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)): error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'rast': argument "FUN" is missing, with no default".

Reading the Terra documentation doesn't seem to help clarify how to write a simple interpolation function for a SpatRaster object.

Comment: Try `terra::focal(..... fun=mean, na.policy="only", na.rm=T)` function.

Comment: There are lots of ways to interpolate point data. Have you tried looking at `terra::interpolate` or `terra::interpIDW`?

Comment: If you are interested, you could more formally interpolate the missing values by kriging using the `automap::autoKrige()` function.  It is a little more convoluted, but it provides an error estimate of your interpolated values.  If you are interested, I can write a dummy example for you.  I definitely understand if you want something more straightforward.